# What's the easiest way for a third party to malleate a transaction?

Tags: transaction-malleability

Let's say I am a node. A transaction has been relayed to me, and one of the `scriptSig` fields is:

`<sig> <pubKey>`

1. **What is the easiest way for me to malleate this transaction?**

   - For example, could I just add a "dummy" opcode to it, like this: `OP_NOP <sig> <pubKey>`?
2. Also, are certain types of scriptSig easier to malleate than others?

Basically, I'm interested in the most practical way a third party might go about malleating a transaction.

Comment: I don't believe adding a dummy opcode would work.  You can't change the payload of the transaction at all without invalidating the signature - that's a key property of any usable digital signature algorithm.  Instead, you have to keep the payload the same, but modify the format of the signature itself.

Comment: Adding a dummy opcode would actually be valid, however the result would be non-standard at least in Bitcoin Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to malleate a transaction is to just change the signature from Low-S to High-S and vice versa.